# Best way to capture error from database firebase javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, error-handling

I have this code, but i don't know how capture a error.

```
  const coleccionRef = database.ref('test');
  coleccionRef.on('value', snapshot => {
    snapshot.val();
  });
```

Any idea?

Comment: you may check that you have a data or empty with `if(snapshot.exists()) { // do something with data } else {//there is no data}` https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your client doesn't have permission to read from the reference, Firebase will invoke the (optional) second callback that you can pass in to `on()`. E.g.

```
const coleccionRef = database.ref('test');
coleccionRef.on('value', snapshot => {
  snapshot.val();
}, error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

I recommend reading the [Firebase reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) for finding more tidbits like this.